# Grep beginning of line

Tags: grep, sed, regex, text-processing

I have a file with the following contents:

```
(((jfojfojeojfow 
//
hellow_rld
(((jfojfojeojfow
//
hellow_rld
```

How can I extract every line that starts with a parenthesis?

Answer (score 44):

The symbol for the beginning of a line is `^`. So, to print all lines whose first character is a `(`, you would want to match `^(`:

1. `grep`

   ```
   grep '^(' file
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   sed -n '/^(/p' file
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Using `perl`

```
perl -ne '/^\(/ && print' foo
```

Output:

```
(((jfojfojeojfow 
(((jfojfojeojfow
```

---

*Explanation (regex part)*

- `/^\(/`

  - `^` assert position at start of the string
  - `\(` matches the character `(` literally

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `bash` one liner:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ^\( ]] && echo "$line"; done <file.txt
```

Here we are reading each line of input and if the line starts with `(`, the line is printed. The main test is done by `[[ $i =~ ^\( ]]`.

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('('):
            print line.rstrip()
```

Here `line.startswith('(')` checks if the line starts with `(`, if so then the line is printed.

Answer (score 4):

#### awk

`awk '/^\(/' testfile.txt`

Result

```
$ awk '/^\(/' testfile.txt                   
(((jfojfojeojfow 
(((jfojfojeojfow
```

#### Python

As python one-liner:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print "\n".join([x.strip() for x in sys.stdin.readlines() if x.startswith("(")])' < input.txt    
(((jfojfojeojfow
(((jfojfojeojfow
```

Or alternatively:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,re;[sys.stdout.write(x) for x in open(sys.argv[1]) if re.search("^\(",x)]' input.txt
```

#### BSD look

`look` is one of the classic but little known Unix utilities, which appeared way back in AT&T Unix version 7. From `man look`:

> The look utility displays any lines in file which contain string as a prefix

The result:

```
$ look "(" input.txt
(((jfojfojeojfow 
(((jfojfojeojfow
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the grep command for this. Assuming the file with the mentioned content is called t.txt:

```
user:~$ grep '^(' t.txt
(((jfojfojeojfow
(((jfojfojeojfow
```

With '--color' as further argument you can even see in color in the terminal what matches. This instruction also do not match empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

You may do the inverse.

```
grep -v '^[^(]' file
```

or

```
sed '/^[^(]/d' file
```

Comment: If the input file contains empty lines, the blank lines are also displayed.